# Numerical equation solving with FindRoot and BandpassFilter

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have problems combining filtering of a data list and `FindRoot`. Here is an example:

```
data := {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3};
Testf[c1_] := BandpassFilter[data, {2*Pi*c1, 2*Pi*0.5}][[1]];
Plot[BandpassFilter[data, {2*Pi*x, 2*Pi*0.5}][[1]], {x, 0.1, 0.5}]
FindRoot[Testf[x] == 0, {x, 0.3, 0.4}]
```

[image: Testf is a well behaved function]

> During evaluation of In[277]:= BandpassFilter::freq: {2 [Pi] x,3.14159} should be a vector of two non-negative, ordered real numbers or a list of such vectors.
> During evaluation of In[277]:= FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in FindRoot[Testf[x]==0,{x,0.3,0.4}].
>
> `FindRoot[Testf[x] == 0, {x, 0.3, 0.4}]`

Please let me know why `BandpassFilter` does not work as other functions here and how to fix this code.

Comment: Use `Testf[c1_?NumericQ] := ...` when you define your function ?

Comment: I get a completely different plot when I run your code to that shown in the question, which is discontinuous

Comment: I tried Testf[c1_?NumericQ] := ... and also Ulrich below, but it does not change the result or solve the problem. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @KraZug: interesting. I run version 11. Ulrich Neumann below obtained what I obtained. I do not see a reason for a discontinuity.

Comment: @Frieder, yes, on version 11.3 your code gives your plot, on version 12 I get discontinuous sections. Also on version 11.3 putting `?NumericQ` works provided I have cleared the original definition.

Comment: @KraZug: Yes, I am running 11.1 here. Indeed, if I clear the definition of Testf first, then Testf[c1_?NumericQ]:=... works. My mistake was not to do Clear[Testf] first. Great, you have solved the problem!

Comment: @Frieder, that's fine. I have submitted a bug report regarding `BandpassFilter` more generally in v12, it is giving completely different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of ?NumericQ indeed helps. Be careful to clear Testf first though:

```
Clear[Testf]
data := {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3};
Testf[c1_?NumericQ] := BandpassFilter[data, {2*Pi*c1, 2*Pi*0.5}][[1]];
Plot[BandpassFilter[data, {2*Pi*x, 2*Pi*0.5}][[1]], {x, 0.1, 0.5}]
FindRoot[Testf[x] == 0, {x, 0.3, 0.4}]
```

Output is then the same plot as in the question and:

```
{x -> 0.336227}
```

Then:

```
In[61]:= Testf[x /. %]

Out[61]= -2.73219*10^-16
```

as expected. Thanks to LouisB and KraZug.

Answer (score 3):

`FindRoot` expects a function as first argument.
Try

```
tf = FunctionInterpolation[Testf[x], {x, .1, .5}]
Plot[tf[x], {x, .1, .5}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[tf[x] == 0, {x, 0.3, 0.4}]
(*{x -> 0.335848}*)
```

Comment: Thank you. This approximation gives Testf[0.335848] evaluates to -0.00182745, which is reasonable, but still an approx. only. Why does the original idea not work?

Comment: Sorry don't know why. I tried `Testf[c1_?NumericQ] := ...` , as suggested by @LouisB (thanks),  without succes.